# if statement and input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very very new to python and I don't know much. My code isn't working and I don't know why, Please help.

```
input = input("Please Enter Something >>> ")
if input is equal to ("Dogs"):
    print "You put Dogs"
else:
    print "You did not put Dogs"
```

Please Help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: We expect you to first go back to your educational materials and try to find out why your program fails -- look at the syntax of an `if` statement.  Second, we expect you to fully describe your problem: this includes the entire error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use print method you have to put in brackets, and you cannot say "is equal too", you have to put "==" Here is the fixed code:

```
input = input("Please Enter Something >>> ")
if input == "Dogs":
    print ("You put Dogs")
else:
    print ("You did not put Dogs")
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that python doesn't know what `is equal to` means. What you want in this case is `==`. Also, don't use `input` as a variable name as that is the name of a built-in function.

Speaking of which, `input` tries to execute the user's input as actual python code, so don't use that. What you want instead is `raw_input`, which will return the actual string that a user entered.

```
user_input = raw_input("Please Enter Something >>> ")
if user_input == "Dogs":
    print "You put Dogs"
```

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
user_input = input("Please Enter Something >>> ")
if input == 'Dogs':
    print ('You put Dogs')
else:
    print ('You did not put Dogs')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have done some mistakes:
1: You cannot use "is equal to" . Use ==
2: Now check whether you are using Python 2 or 3
   if you are using python 2 then you can write print"dog" like this.
   For python 3 you have to put round brackets like print("dog")